# Iterate through a list and extract last char

Tags: r

I want to present you a case it is keeping me few hours busy:
while trying to iterate through a list to extract the last character from it, I need the last letter, which identifies the size of the t-shirt:

```
  Lineitem.name
1 T-Shirt Donna "Si dai. Ciao." - M

2 T-Shirt Donna "Honey" - L

3 T-Shirt Donna "Si dai. Ciao." - M

4 T-Shirt Donna "I do very bad things" - M

5 T-Shirt Donna "Si dai. Ciao." - M

6 T-Shirt Donna "Stai nel tuo (mind your business)" - White / S

7 T-Shirt Donna "Stay Stronz" - White / L

8 T-Shirt Donna "Stay Stronz" - White / M

9 T-Shirt Donna "Si dai. Ciao." - S

10 T-Shirt Donna "Je suis esaurit" - Black / S
```

so far I tried like this:

```
 tshirt_sizes <- orders[18] #18 because its the 18th column in my df
 subst = function(x,n){
  substring(x,nchar(x)-n+1)
 }
 #looping through the list 
 typeof(tshirt_sizes)

 for(i in tshirt_sizes[]) {
   tshirt_sizes[2] <- subst(i, 1)
   }
 #Using this for loop i get this error:
  Error in nchar(x) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector 

 #second attempt using apply()
 apply(tshirt_sizes,1, subst)
 #Using this i get this error: 
 Error in substring(x, nchar(x) - n + 1) : 
   argument "n" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in one line through the magic of regular expressions:

```
gsub('.*(.)$', '\\1', orders[[18]])
```

Note the use of double brackets (`orders[[18]]`), since `gsub` requires a vector, not a list. The regular expression is saying, "return the single character that appears just before the end of the string".

Since you are interested specifically in the last character of each string, you could also avoid regular expressions and do it this way:

```
split <- strsplit(orders[[18]], '')
reversed <- lapply(split, rev)
last_char <- lapply(reversed, '[', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now I've got a  character type, and I need a list, is it possible to return to the original format?

Comment: `sub` will do it. It's just one substitution. +1

Comment: And how can I use a regular expression for the same but, for example, the last 2 or 3 characters?

Comment: A regular expression such as `'.*(.{2})$'` would grab the last 2 characters, specifically.